# Chaining promises by iterating an array

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Is there a way to chain promises by iterating through an array?

For example, I'm trying to convert the content of multiple tabs into their own separate pdf pages using jsPDF and html2canvas.

```
const pdf = new jsPDF('l');

let index = 1;
let input = document.getElementById('print');

const formatPage = (canvas) => {
    const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg');
    pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 10, 10, 200, 100, '', 'FAST', 0);
      
}

const nextPage = () => {
    pdf.addPage();
    document.getElementById(`${tabs[index]}`).click();
    index++;
    input = document.getElementById('print');
}

html2canvas(input)
      .then(canvas => {
        formatPage(canvas);
        nextPage();
        return html2canvas(input);
      })
      .then(canvas => {
        formatPage(canvas);
        nextPage();
        return html2canvas(input);
      })
      .then(canvas => {
        formatPage(canvas);
        pdf.save('download.pdf');
      })
```

Is there a way to do the same thing through iteration of the tabs array? I want to be able to chain a dynamic number of promises instead of hard coding it because for example, every page might not have the same number of tabs.

Solution:

I couldn't get it to work with Promise.all() but this is how I did it.

```
async generatePages() {
      for(let index = 0; index !== tabs.length; index++) {
           document.getElementById(`${tabs[index]}`).click();
           input = document.getElementById('print');
           await this.processPage(input, index, tabs.length - 1);
    }
}

processPage(input, index, end) {
    const formatPage = (canvas) => {
      const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg');
      pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 10, 10, 200, 100, '', 'FAST', 0);
    }

    return html2canvas(input).then(canvas => {
      formatPage(canvas);

      if(index !== end) {
        pdf.addPage();
      } else {
        pdf.save('download.pdf');
      }
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create an array of Promise objects, and then use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to resolve them.

```js
let promises = []

promises.push(promise1)
promises.push(promise2)
promises.push(promise3)

Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
  results.forEach(result => {
  // do something with results
  })
})
```

Comment: I would recommend something similar but mapping to promises: `Promise.all(tabs.map(tab => /* content of the for loop block here */))`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but, from what you want I could possibly recommend the following steps:

- You want to iterate through the tabs
- You want to get all content from each tab (I'm not sure about this one)
- You create a promise with `html2canvas` with each content
- You process all the promises for each content with `Promise.promiseAll`
- You iterate the `resolved` promises
- You format them and add more pages if it is not the last one, otherwise you save the PDF

This is approximately how the implementation should look like:

```
const tabsElements = document.querySelectorAll(`.tab`);
const tabsContentPromises = tabsElements.reduce((acc, tabEl) => {
  const input = tabEl.querySelector('input');

  return acc.push(html2canvas(input));
}, []);

const pdf = new jsPDF('l');

const formatPage = (canvas) => {
  const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg');
  pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 10, 10, 200, 100, '', 'FAST', 0);
}

Promise.promiseAll(tabsContentPromises).then(tabsContentCanvas => {
  tabsContentCanvas.forEach((contentCanvas, index) => {
    formatPage(contentCanvas);
    
    if (index !== (tabsContentCanvas.length - 1)) {  
      pdf.addPage();
    } else {
      pdf.save('download.pdf');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, `Promise.all` is certainly the way to go, but you need to get an array of promises, so you need to map your array of tabs to their processed promise:

```js
generatePages() {
    return Promise.all(tabs.map((tab, index) => {
       document.getElementById(`${tab}`).click();
       input = document.getElementById('print');
       return this.processPage(input, index, tabs.length - 1);
    }));
}
```

Comment: I tried but it just ended up rendering the first tab for every page. The solution I did using async/await seemed to be the only one that managed to click and render every tab correctly.